# ListView Overlays EditText when Scrolling

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have the following linear layout. In the below situation, filler layout and the textview turn to View.GONE and the ListView is set to VISIBLE, as well as the editText on top. Everything seems fine, however when I scroll the below happens with the text from the listview overlaying my editText. Also, at the bottom of the screen there is a gap between the end of the listView and the bottom of the screen, which I would not want to be there, I want it to be attached to the  bottom of the screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#45D199"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:weightSum="100"
android:clipChildren="false"
tools:context=".City_Search">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/edit_txt"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:hint="Name of the City..."
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:maxLength="15"
    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="65dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="35"
    android:id="@+id/filler_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="0dp"></LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/search_txt"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Name of the City..."
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="90"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_height="0dp"></ListView>
```

[image]

Comment: What is `filler_layout`?

Comment: It's a layout used to fill space to position the other items above and below it.

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung why did you delete your answer?

Comment: post your full xml, not getting what is shown in image above ?

Comment: I think the answer provided little information. I actually want to go for `RelativeLayout` or `fragment` in this case to keep the `layout` clean and tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code.Its help you something

```
 - <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:id="@+id/main_layout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="#45D199"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       tools:context=".City_Search">

       <EditText
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
           android:id="@+id/edit_txt"
           android:textSize="25sp"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:background="@android:color/transparent"
           android:hint="Name of the City..."
           android:visibility="invisible"
           android:maxLines="1"
           android:maxLength="15"
           android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
           android:layout_height="65dp" />

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_weight="35"
           android:id="@+id/filler_layout"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:layout_height="0dp"></LinearLayout>


       <TextView
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
           android:id="@+id/search_txt"
           android:layout_weight="10"
           android:textSize="25sp"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:text="Name of the City..."
           android:layout_height="0dp" />

       <ListView
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:id="@+id/list_view"
           android:background="#FFFFFF"
           android:visibility="gone"
           android:layout_height="0dp"></ListView>

   </LinearLayout>
```